# How do I remove my library from Cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

Due to some ownership issues, I now manage two Cocoapods libraries that are essentially duplicates of each other, with separate names on Cocoapods. I'd like to take one down, and just maintain one of them, for simplicity.
**Is there any way to remove a library that I manage from the Cocoapods trunk?**
I know that very few, if any people, are using the wrongly named library. But as the library gains popularity, more people are finding and including the wrong (and now outdated) version when they search on Cocoapods.

Comment: why don't you contact the manager of Cocoapods?

Comment: The last 3 FAQ [entries here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/pull/12199) I guess.

Comment: @DanielA.White there are thousands of libraries in Cocoapods, so I didn't want to bug them unnecessarily :) I think Rangad's link contains the answer: push the deprecated flag to all versions of the old library. I'll try it out and report back!

Comment: The accepted answer (answered by CocoaPod contributor Keith Smiley) gives instructions on how to do this. It's the same approach that's hinted at in the FAQ's referenced above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [`deprecated_in_favor_of`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deprecated_in_favor_of) attribute to the old specs you no longer want to maintain. This will notify users when they run `pod install` that they should switch to the other spec. You'll need to submit a pull request to the [specs repo](https://github.com/cocoapods/specs) with this change.